# Alexa not responding for when i created skill from skill buidler

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have created custom skill intent called EmergencyIntent by using the skill builder beta.

Now the problem is it's not asking **Intent confirmation**  as I configured in skill builder.

[image: Created EmergencyIntent, added sample utterance as emergency detected. then intent confirm message added]

[image: Added emergencyIntent in index.js]

tried like this also

[image: Without giving output message]

[image: Test result is empty when I say emergency detected]

**why it's not asking for intent confirmation?**

Comment: I have fixed this issue using   'EmergencyIntent': function() {
   //this.response.speak(':confirm');
   this.emit(':delegate')
  },

Answer (score 0):

From your comment it looks like you've resolved your issue. But, I thought I'd add that you could also check the dialog state before emitting your final response. Something like...

```
let dialogState = this.event.request.dialogState;
try {
  if (dialogState == "STARTED" || dialogState == "IN_PROGRESS") {
    this.emit(":delegate");
  }
} catch(err) {
  console.log("Error: " + err.message);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But in my case above code causing some issue.

Comment: User:  Alexa play songs/musician </br>
Alexa: Do you want to play any specific songs? </br>

if User says: Yes </br>

Alexa: Are you looking for any specific songs? </br>
User: YES</br>
Alexa:   artist your looking for? </br>
User: artist name</br>
Alexa: movies your looking for? </br>
User: movie name</br>
Alexa: album your looking for? </br>
User: album name</br>
// after all questions
Alexa: Okay playing songs form artist/album/movie name
if User says: No </br>
Alexa: Okay playing songs  </br>
//Alexa should stop asking questions and it will play some songs

Comment: When i'm saying NO it should stop ask other questions

Comment: Where should I get slot value? ' let dialogState = this.event.request.dialogState;
try {
  if (dialogState == "STARTED" || dialogState == "IN_PROGRESS") {
    this.emit(":delegate");
  }
} catch(err) {
  console.log("Error: " + err.message);
}'

Comment: I'm not sure I'm exactly following the dialog logic but to deal with yes/no questions you have two options - use the dialog interface (see: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/dialog-interface-reference.html) and/or the AMAZON.YesIntent and AMAZON.NoIntent in which case you'd probably want to use state handlers so you could use the responses to yes/no for different questions. (see: https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs#making-skill-state-management-simpler).

Comment: I read the dialog example you provided again and I'm still not following the conversation flow. Wouldn't a user just say something like: 'Alexa, ask {invocation-name} to play {songName} by {artistName}? Or, 'Alexa, ask {invocation-name} to play songs by {artistName}. Where the response to elicit the {songName} might be: 'Okay, which song by {artistName} would you like me to play?'